# what logic is needed for validating before and after count of elements after deleting one element. I have written the below logic which doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, automation

```
class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String orders="6 orders";
                String[] orderstextsplit= orders.split(" "); //6 | orders
                String order_count = orderstextsplit[0]; //6
                int actualcount = Integer.parseInt(order_count); //6
                System.out.println("Actual count is:" +actualcount);
```

//code for deleting an element (not included here)
//code after deleting an element (below)

```
 int expected count= actual count -1;
                if(actualcount==expectedcount)
                {
                 System.out.println("Bookmarks count is " +driver.findElement(orderscount));
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: How are you deleting the element? Is it from the UI?

Comment: Yes deleting from the UI